# asp.net core prerender webpack error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter'

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, webpack, prerender

I have error when i try prerender: `asp-prerender-webpack-config="webpack.config.js"` to my app.

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server"
     asp-prerender-webpack-config="webpack.config.js">Loading...</app>
```

Error:

> > An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'filter' of undefined at
>   D:\projects\aspnetocore-angular2\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\LoadViaWebpack.js:80:54
>   at initializePromise
>   (D:\projects\aspnetocore-angular2\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\node_modules\es6-promise\dist\es6-promise.js:459:5)
>   at new Promise
>   (D:\projects\aspnetocore-angular2\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\node_modules\es6-promise\dist\es6-promise.js:871:31)
>   at loadViaWebpackNoCache
>   (D:\projects\aspnetocore-angular2\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\LoadViaWebpack.js:34:12)
>   at Object.loadViaWebpack
>   (D:\projects\aspnetocore-angular2\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\LoadViaWebpack.js:19:49)
>   at findBootModule
>   (D:\projects\aspnetocore-angular2\node_modules\aspnet-prerendering\Prerendering.js:95:29)
>   at findBootFunc
>   (D:\projects\aspnetocore-angular2\node_modules\aspnet-prerendering\Prerendering.js:103:5)
>   at renderToString
>   (D:\projects\aspnetocore-angular2\node_modules\aspnet-prerendering\Prerendering.js:10:5)
>   at module.exports.renderToString

webpack file:

```
    var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
var merge = require('webpack-merge');
var allFilenamesExceptJavaScript = /\.(?!js(\?|$))([^.]+(\?|$))/;

// Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
var sharedConfig = {
    resolve: { extensions: [ '', '.js', '.ts' ] },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, loader: 'ts', query: { silent: true } },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'to-string!css' },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, loader: 'url', query: { limit: 25000 } }
        ]
    }
};

// Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
var clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.ts' },
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, './wwwroot/dist') },
    devtool: isDevBuild ? 'inline-source-map' : null,
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        // Plugins that apply in production builds only
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ])
});

// Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
var serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot-server.ts' },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
    },
    target: 'node',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    externals: [nodeExternals({ whitelist: [allFilenamesExceptJavaScript] })] // Don't bundle .js files from node_modules
});

module.exports = [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? 

I'm getting a bit sick of arcane Angular2/webpack errors!!

Comment: Show your Startup with app.Use...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a long time, and i'm suspecting it's a bug. I have a workaround, remove `asp-prerender-webpack-config` attribute from tag and configure webpack to output transpiled file to another file with the same name. Be sure you add `libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'` to webpack config file in order to make it work since it required you export your boot function this way: `module.exports`. By default webpack doesn't exports anything, you must specify this by yourself. Below the codesnippets required to make it work as it works for me:

`clients.jsx`

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");

var Test = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (<h1>Hello!</h1>);
    }
});

module.exports = function (params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         resolve({
             html: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Test />)
        });
    });
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
/// <binding ProjectOpened='Watch - Development' />

var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var MODULES = path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot/modules");

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules']
    },
    entry: {
        clients: MODULES + "/clients.jsx"
    },
    output: {
        path: MODULES,
        filename: "[name].js",
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
          {
              test: /\.jsx?/,
              include: MODULES,
              loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [],
    target: "node"
};
```

`Index.cshtml`

```
<div id="clients" asp-prerender-module="wwwroot/modules/clients"
     asp-prerender-data="@Model" ></div>
```

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ]
}
```

`packages.json`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^1.0.7",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.17",
    "aspnet-webpack-react": "^1.0.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  }
```

So the react components will reside in: `./wwwroot/modules` and inside that folder will reside both `clients.jsx` and `clients.js`.